# How can I change CSS properties dynamically without using the .css( ) method in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div in my HTML code. I want to change it's background color to red (red for example, but it can be another color), but i don't want to use the .css() method in Jquery because the .css() method makes something like this in my HTML code:

```
<div id="my_div" style="background-color: red"> Elements inside my div </div>
```

**I don't want the style attribute in my HTML code**, but what can I do to change css dynamically whitout using that?

**Updated:** I can't use classes because the color won't always be red, it can be blue, yellow, purple, or an hexadecimal color.

Comment: Why does the style attribute so bother you?

Comment: @VisioN It is bad practice to mix document structure and markup. As is it to mix markup and logic (Javascript). If you use classes like João Silva suggests in his answer, you can assign a relevant class to an element, and keep the styling in the CSS.

Comment: it is worth remembering that it's only in the DOM, not in the HTML. @GolezTrol, if the `style` attributes are added with JavaScript and amended by JavaScript in order to further increase JavaScript's capacity to use and interact with the page, why is it bad?

Comment: @VisioN same reason it should bother everyone, probably. It's too hard to maintain a million inline styles in any kind of production-sized project

Comment: @VisioN also, what GolexTrol said

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: jQuery does nothing to the HTML so there is nothing to maintain. Using the `.width()` function adds an inline style. How do you replace it with a class?

Comment: Seriously, people: it's added by JavaScript, to achieve and implement programmatic/functional requirements. It's not *in* the HTML. It's used for interactivity.

Comment: @Blender I didn't say anything about jQuery :) I was referring to inline styles in HTML markup, just as VisioN was

Comment: I would highly recommend the best ranked answer, that of adding a class in the CSS and toggling it with the Javascript. For example, use the class `active` instead of the color `red` if you plan to use different colors throughout the document. Style the `active` class to be red in one area, blue in another (eg: `#header .active { background: blue; }`). _This is_ the proper division of content (HTML), layout (CSS), and logic (JS). Pretty much the only time you should put CSS styles into the JS is if they are being dynamically generated as part of some psychedelic demo :-p

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt, sort of, but VisioN was referring to the `style` attribute *added by JavaScript* (as mentioned in the question itself).

Comment: @Blender oh, didn't read the question entirely. In that case, I mean, everything that deals with style ultimately edits the html...

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I was referring to inline styles that are dynamically set by jQuery. Let's not mix the things.

Comment: @DavidThomas It's still markup, which does belong in neither the HTML nor the JavaScript code. And neither does addClass('red'). See my answer below.

Comment: @GolezTrol: The DOM isn't markup.

Comment: @GolezTrol yup, this is the preferred way to handle things

Comment: @Blender Okay, wrong word. It's presentation. You don't want to specify how things look in either HTML or Javascript. Just specify what kind of information it is, and let the style sheets define how that information is shown.

Comment: @DavidThomas what you said it was the thing that I wanted to hear. I have told my "instructor" that the style attribute added by Jquery it's not bad, but he wanted me to find some way to not use it. But now I'm gonna tell him that i't can't be done in another way.

Thanks to everybody, I'm not good at English so i couldn't understand very much your comments, but they helped me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @GolezTrol: If that was the case, then why is the `style` attribute still around? As I said before, classes can't be used for *everything* CSS-related.

Comment: That's an ignorant question. Backwards compatibility is important, and apart from that, there are always exceptions (style is often used for animations/transitions, for one). But in general, classes do help to separate presentation from logic, and in most of the cases like this, there's no need for any specific css properties being in your Javascript, and especially not a color.

Answer (score 6):

You can use CSS classes:

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

$("#my_div").addClass("red");
```

If you have more than one color, you can create multiple classes, but this somehow defeats the generalization purpose of using a class, as @pst mentioned in the comments, and you might be better using `css()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but i can't use clases because my color won't always be red, it can be another one

Comment: @user1598505 And therein lies the crux of the problem. The goal is a one-off specialization while CSS classes are generalization. Inline styles *are* the way to get one-off specializations .. while it is possible to define *dynamic* style-sheets (say to create a class-per-element), that is another can of worms.

Comment: @user1598505: so you don't want to use `css()` because it somehow offends you, and you can't use actual CSS classes because things won't always be presented in the same way. What options do you imagine remain?

Answer (score 3):

Assigning a class, like João Silva suggests, is the preferred way to go, but assigning the class 'red' is almost as bad as setting the color though the style property. You still got markup ('color=red') in your document and javascript.

Rather assign a relevant name, that shows what is the state of that element, for example.

```
$("div.payment").addClass("overdue");
```

Then, you just tell that the element should be shown as 'overdue', and it is up to the CSS definition to define what 'overdue' looks like.

Comment: +1 For clarifying (IMOHO *proper*) use of CSS classes and separation of "how" and "what". Not sure if it meets the OPs (envisioned) goals, though.

Comment: It was just an example, since I don't know the context. Obviously, I agree with giving a meaningful name to the class, such as `overdue`. Also, seems like OP wants to use other colors such as blue, yellow, or an hexadecimal color, so I don't think they really have a semantic meaning other than the color itself.

Comment: @JoãoSilva I know. That's why I upvoted your answer as well. But I felt I needed to clear this up, also because of the discussion in the comments on the question. People don't seem to see the difference.

Comment: Yes, quite a discussion, eh? Sure, you have explained it quite well, just wanted to point out that I don't actually agree with using names such as `red` as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can Set the class="" attribute and define a Background Color in the Stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any other method of adding styles to your elements other than CSS or class.

I prefer adding the class names as it leads to cleaner code..
I am sure that you know what the colors are beforehand , be it hexadecimal .. 
You can create separate class names of all the colors you are going to use and just add the class to the elements..
It will make your code well defined..

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to mess with the dom style shits you may use the following.

```js
function changeCSS(selector, values) {
 Object.values(document.styleSheets).forEach(s => {
  try {
   if ('cssRules' in s) {
    Object.values(s.cssRules).forEach(c => {
     if (c.selectorText === selector) {
      Object.assign(c.style, values);
     }
    });
   }
  } catch { }
 });
}

const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black', 'pink', 'white'];
let pos = 0;

function setColor() {
 changeCSS('.test-class', { color: colors[pos], 'background-color': colors[5 - pos] });
 pos = (pos + 1) % 6;
}
```

```css
.test-class {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 33px;
}
```

```html
<span class="test-class" onclick="setColor()">Click me please</span>
```